# Elasticsearch fuzzylike this query with multiple values in like_text

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. We are using a fuzzy_like_this query as below

```
{
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "flt": {
                                "fields": [
                                  "actor.id"
                                ],
                                "like_text": "kar@gmail.com"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "size": "100",
                      "sort": [
                        {
                          "published": {
                            "order": "desc",
                            "ignore_unmapped": true
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
```

The like_text currently matches single string, we want to modify it to search for comma seperated values i.e `"like_text": "kar@gmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com"`

I tried analyzer and match options in flt but unable to get the expected result.Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need the fuzzy query? Have you tried just using a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)? You can configure lots of options, but by default the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used to tokenize your query text, and it will tokenize on commas.

As an illustration, I created a simple index and added a few docs:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"email": "kar@gmail.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"email": "xyz@yahoo.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"email": "somebody@somewhereelse.com"}
```

then ran a simple match query, and got back the expected results:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "email": "kar@gmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.43920785,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "AhjrGCcXSjW26eNDDYENHA",
            "_score": 0.43920785,
            "_source": {
               "email": "kar@gmail.com"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "X7Fk6J1TQMWK5ZccsfBrVA",
            "_score": 0.43920785,
            "_source": {
               "email": "xyz@yahoo.com"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used (if you're using ES 1.4 you'll have to enable CORS to be able to use the code in the browser):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/633c2d284979b26406040db90815231ba71513bc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. we tried match query.  It solved our problem however not in the straight forward way as you suggested. The comma seperated email ids are not returning data may be because the field is marked as "not_analysed" . Instead we added multiple match as follows    and it solved our problem . "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "actor.id": "kar@tdfsdfs.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "actor.id": "xyz@sdofsd.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }